# Boolean True or False upon finding two consecutive digits in a given integer without using any built-in functions

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, iteration

To find two consecutive digits(D) in a given integer(N) without using any built-in functions and returning True or False, the following code seems to be exiting when coming across one D, however it works if there are two Ds. Why is it not working as it is and how to fix it? Thanks!

```
def double_digits(n, d):
    """Return True if N has two Ds in a row otherwise return False.

    int, int -> Boolean

    >>> double_digits(91019, 1)
    False
    >>> double_digits(88, 8)
    True
    >>> double_digits(2772, 7)
    True
    >>> double_digits(88108, 0)
    False
    >>> double_digits(12345, 4)
    False
    >>> double_digits(81811081, 1)
    True
    """
    while n > 0:
        remainder = n % 10
        n = n // 10
        if remainder == d:
            if n % 10 == d:
                return True
            else:
                remainder, n = n % 10, n // 10
    return False
```

Comment: Your `while` loop always returns on the first iteration. That's probably not what you need it to do.

Comment: Probably the final `return False` is indented too far, though I haven't yet checked the logic completely.

Comment: What exactly do you consider to be a "built-in function" and why such an arbitrary limitation exist? This can be solved with no math at all, just a simple `for` loop that remembers the previous iteration. FWIW, not too sure about `%`, but `==`, `//` and '>' also trigger a "built-in function"

Comment: @DeepSpace How do you get each digit of an int value without any math?

Comment: @mks You need to count how many times the given digit occurs in a row.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice `for digit in str(n):` then convert `d` to `str` as well

Comment: @DeepSpace I see what you mean. There is almost certainly math happening in that `str()` call.

Comment: I think you are not understanding the problem. The way I will do this is to convert the digits into a string, in that way you can loop over each digit of the string and check with the next digit whether they are equal or not

Comment: @Code-Apprentice There is also probably a lot of math when generating the byte code. What's the point?

Comment: @DeepSpace Generating byte code is in the Python interpreter, not the program this OP is writing.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice wouldn't that make this code longer? It already is, I feel. Counting would make sense if it weren't asking for consecutive Ds. Or maybe triple or more consecutive Ds.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice the math that `str` is supposedly doing is also not in the program this OP is writing. I still don't get your point.

Comment: @EnriqueBet Can't use built-in functions.

Comment: @mks Well, clearly to make the code do what you want it to do, you have to add something. So "wouldn't that make this code longer" isn't a very good objection.

Comment: Thank you @alani. Yep, that seems to be the problem. Why is it so when n is still > 0? and how do I fix it?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice, no objection. Just a beginner's question. Trying to figure this out for practice.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice He does that by testing both `remainder` (the current digit) and `n % 10` (the preceding digit).

Comment: I thought your code doesn't look for the consecutive digits, but after closer examination, I see you are with the two if statements. I suggest you read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code so you can find the problem.

Comment: @Barmar I see that now after a closer look at the code.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You must de-indent the last statement : return False, 4 spaces to the left. That must help you.
Alternatively you can convert the input to a string and then the character matching would be easy.

```
def double_digits(n: int, d: int)->bool:
    n = str(n)
    d = str(d)
    i = 0
    while i < len(n)-1:
        if n[i] == d and n[i+1] == d:
            return True
        i+=1
    return False
```

Here I have used some builtin fuctions like `len` and `str`, but if you explicitly
want to avoid using them, just go with your original approach and just de-indent the return statement once

Comment: You de-indented too far, it's not in the function any more.

Comment: `len(n-1)` should be `len(n) - 1`, Python uses `and` (not `&&`) and  there is going to be an infinite loop since `i` always stays 0

Comment: That's it. Wrong indentation. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The last return statement should be out of the loop.
Below is the correct code:

```
   def double_digits(n, d): 
    while n > 0:
        remainder = n % 10
        n = n // 10
        if remainder == d:
            if n % 10 == d:
                return True
            else:
                remainder, n = n % 10, n // 10
    return False
```

Comment: 1. Correct and fixed.
2. else clause is reducing iterations. Try it at http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html with double_digits(91019, 1)

Comment: Yeah, just corrected my answer, missed the part which makes sure if the other char is not d you discard it when you checked it.